# HttpClient Angular 2 return "null instead "False"

Tags: angular, httpclient

I am using angular 4 HttpClient to call my api. I can get "True" and "False" correctly using Postman and always get "null" for "False" and True for "True" using httpclient in angular 4. Has anyone had a similar experience?

This is not an off topic question. I think there is a bug in the httpclient that converts the "false" or 0 to null. I spent several days and scratch my head to find the reason.

```
get(path) {
  return this.http.get(path);
}
```

This statement always returns null instead false as supposed to be.

Comment: can you post some code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the reason. There is a problem in the Httpclient to convert "False" or 0 to a similar angular variable for the api get call.

```
getNonJson (path) {
  return this.http.get(path, { responseType: 'text' });
}
```

I have to get it as text format, then I convert it to Boolean.